# How to locate an element by using any of the selenium web driver locators

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Website URL**: https://staging.corporatehousingbyowner.com/

Hi,
I am unable to locate and click at the following button present in a UL > li through Selenium Webdriver with Java.
Using Chrome driver to perform automated execution.

```
<ul>
<li><a class="list-your-prop" href="/dashboard/properties/add/">List Your Property</a></li>
<ul/>
```

Already tried the following solutions.

1:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("List Your Property"));
        element.click();
```

2:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("menu-text"));
String elementText = element.getText();
```

3:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(@class,'list-your-prop')]/ul/li/a"));
        element.click();
```

4: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > header:nth-child(1) > nav:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > ul:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(4) > a:nth-child(1)")).click();`

[WebPage Highlights][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH2LR.png

Please help, **thanks in advance**.

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** web elements with `List Your Property.`

The below xpath has unique entry in `HTMLDOM`

```
//div[@id='myNavbar']/descendant::a[text()='List Your Property']
```

**Code trial 1 :**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='myNavbar']/descendant::a[text()='List Your Property']")); 
element.click();
```

**Code trial 2 :** **With Explicit waits:**

```
WebElement element  = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='myNavbar']/descendant::a[text()='List Your Property']")));
element.click();
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://staging.corporatehousingbyowner.com/");
WebElement element  = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='myNavbar']/descendant::a[text()='List Your Property']")));
element.click();
```

Comment: thanks for prompt response bro. But when Chrome driver runs, this code gets executed with no errors. Yet still the page is not moving to the page where it is supposed to, when clicked at it. Can you check why it is happening?

Comment: @Gulraiz :  See the updated 1 code above, it did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("nav.navbar a.list-your-prop")).click();`

It is also better to use waiters because the element might take time to load.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I will consider this option as well.

Answer (score 0):

> You just need to traverse from parent -> child to identify unique xpath as it's returning 2 elements with class attribute alone.
> Here is the working code :

```
driver.get("https://staging.corporatehousingbyowner.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right']//a[text()='List Your Property']").click()
```